# How to remove sensor controller from LED panel

Tags: led, pwm

I have a led panel that is controlled by a touch sensor. Light if off by default, single press turns light on/off, long press changes light brightness.

The touch sensor is connected to 3 pins: GND, VCC, PWM.
[image: Touch sensor]

How can I remove this touch sensor from circuit so the light is always on and brightness is maximum?

Comment: Do you have a part-number of the IC on the touch sensor?

Comment: It's impossible to say for sure without a circuit diagram.  If you're willing to experiment, try removing the sensor and connecting PWM to VCC.  If that doesn't work, try connecting PWM to GND.